# Override JavaScript function from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a global Ajax javascript file that has a method that gets called after every HTTP request across the application and shows an alert if the request timed out.

However, I want to disable this function during the processing of one specific process and then re-enable it when it's done.

What I've tried doing is this:

```
string jsScriptRemoveEndRequest = "function EndOfRequest(param1, param2) {}";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "EndOfRequest", jsScriptRemoveEndRequest, true);
```

This did not work to override the function.

Then I want to recreate it which I assume doesn't work either:

```
string jScriptAddEndRequest = "function EndOfRequest(param1,param2) {..codehere...};"
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EndOfRequest", jScriptAddEndRequest, true);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've been scouring the web but to no avail.

Comment: have you tried writing a custom decorator with reflection? writing a custom decorator will allow you to decorate other similar functions in your application. reflection will allow you to get the caller.

Comment: Would you have any links or samples I can look at? I'm not very familiar with javascript.

Comment: i was under the impression the code you shared was C#.

Comment: It is, my bad..

Comment: checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection